# Wrong hours converted to epoch time

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, epoch, hour

I'm trying to convert a date with epoch time method.
with these code below

```
long epoch = 0;
try {
    epoch = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse("12/11/2017 23:20:23")
            .getTime();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It gives me the epoch time: `1513052423`

Which once convert give: `Tuesday 12 December 2017 04:20:23` and not `23:20:23` :/

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is long outmoded and notoriously troublesome. Even on Android I recommend you give JSR-310 AKA `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, a thought. It is so much nicer to work with and will give your clearer code. You may use it on Android through [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) SimpleDateFormat is locale-sensitive. Please check or set your timezone

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Comment: Your code is correct. To the usage, locale and time zone are two different concepts, they haven’t really got anything to do with each other. While you may also meaningfully set the formatter’s locale, it isn’t relevant here.